# Square payment unable to test payment flow in iOS app

Tags: ios, square, square-connect

I have developed the demo app with the square payment SDK with sandbox credential to take payment.

Every time I am getting failed error and it' saying

```
Error Domain=SCCAPIErrorDomain Code=6 "User not activated. Please visit https://squareup.com/activate. The logged-in account cannot take credit card payments.  This could be because the account is from a country where Square does not process payments, because the account did not complete the initial activation flow, or because it has been deactivated for security reasons." UserInfo={error_code=user_not_active, NSLocalizedDescription=User not activated. Please visit https://squareup.com/activate. The logged-in account cannot take credit card payments.  This could be because the account is from a country where Square does not process payments, because the account did not complete the initial activation flow, or because it has been deactivated for security reasons.}
```

As I am from India and might be it restrict me to test. It is taking geolocation internally from their POS app and it's out of my hand to look into it.

Is there any way I can test the payment flow? So that I can integrate the same into my live App.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are outside Square's supported countries you will not be able to test card payments with the Square Point of Sale app and API. You can however disable card payments as a tender type and only enable the `CASH` tender. Then you will be able to complete the app switch regardless of location.

Comment: Then how can I develop an app for my client?

Comment: I don't want to use the app in india but as a developer I have developed the app for my US based client and they want square payment integration. How can I complete the development if you are not allowing me to even test sandbox payment for POS. How can I complete my app flow ?  Please give me is it possible or not for development only. We want to integrate in our both Android and iOS app.

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya I was actually mistaken, you can test cash transactions. I'll update my answer

Comment: How can I view transaction id in square dashboard because I can't see an transcation id which I get in my app after successful transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Square Auto detects currency and location when you create a Square account. I faced the same issue when i tried to integrate Square with an existing application for my client in the US and UK.
My suggestion would be ask your client or a contact from US to create and account from there and link an US or UK bank account based on their location. 
Square does support multiple countries like US, UK, Canada, Japan and Australia.
It is mandatory to have a Square account from the country you're client belongs to so that it will be easy to test.
And another suggestion would be try to have two Square accounts since you can have one for staging and one for production as developer account to prevent lots of problems in the future.